# rearrange $z \mapsto z^2 + c$

Tags: arithmetic, complex-numbers, fractals

The Mandelbrot Set:

$Z \mapsto Z² + C$ (or more precisely) $Z_{i+1} = Z_i ^2 + C$

Where $Z$ and $C$ are complex numbers.

Can this well-established equation be rearranged to determine things that would otherwise take a large or infinite number of iterations or tests with different values of $C$?

Such as the smallest bounding box that would contain all values for $C$, where $Z$ bails out in a given iteration.

Comment: They are "vectors" but more specifically, they are complex numbers.

Comment: It is misleading to say the Mandelbrot set looks like $z=z^2+c$. The iterations performed to determine set inclusion are defined by a _map_, thus it would be more appropriate to write $z \rightarrow z^2 + c$, or even better $z_{i+1} = z_i ^2 + c$.

Comment: Thanks tomcuchta and Hooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z$ and $c$ are complex numbers here, represented as points in the complex plane.  The set is not the set of $z=z^2+c$, but the set of points $c$ such that the iteration $c, c^2+c, (c^2+c)^2+c, ((c^2+c)^2+c)^2+c \ldots$ does not go to infinity.

You can certainly use algebra to determine many of the features of the set.  Each bulb has a root of one of these expressions in it, and the edge of the bulb is where the derivative has absolute value $1$.

Comment: How would I find an edge of a given bulb?

Comment: @alan2here:  each bulb has the points repeat after a given number of iterations.  The main bulb has the iterates approaching a given number, so (for given $c$) $z=z^2+c$ or $z=(-c+\sqrt{c^2-4})/2$.  Then take the derivative of $z$ with respect to $c$, set the absolute value to $1$ and you get the main cardioid.  For the circle to the left, it is a 2-cycle, so you need to solve $z=(z^2+c)^2+c$ and so on.